# android setKeyListener event not setting the keys as desired

Tags: android, checkbox, textview

Myself trying to enable/disable a textfield using checkbox as,

```
 tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv);
 cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb);
 tv.setFocusable(false);
 tv.setKeyListener(null);
 tv.setEnabled(false);

  cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked) {
                        tv.setFocusable(true);
                        tv.setEnabled(true);
                        tv.setKeyListener(new DigitsKeyListener(false, true));
                    } else {
                        tv.setFocusable(false);
                        tv.setEnabled(false);
                        tv.setKeyListener(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

The above code is in `onCreate` method. But even when the checkbox checked, the `tv.setKeyListener(new DigitsKeyListener(false, true));` doesn't enabling the keys. Where myself missed?

Comment: doesn't enabling the keys means keyboard does not pop's up ? Or TextView is not getting focused ?

Comment: Keyboard does not popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all those 3 lines of code where you are setting focus to the EditText.

```
tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv);
cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb);

tv.setKeyListener(null);
tv.setEnabled(false);

cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked) {            
            tv.setEnabled(true);
            tv.setKeyListener(new DigitsKeyListener(false, true));
        } else {            
            tv.setEnabled(false);
            tv.setKeyListener(null);
        }
    }
});
```

OR

Replace `tv.setFocusable(boolean)` with `tv.setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean)`;

Comment: It working... Then what is the use of `setFocusable` then?

Comment: Focusable in touch mode should always be set before the focusable flag otherwise, setting the focusable flag will trigger a focusableViewAvailable() which, in touch mode, will not successfully request focus on this view because the focusable in touch mode flag is not set. (From Official Definition)